# Regex to not allow particular special characters at start or end of email name in email address

Tags: regex

I have the following regex condition for email address.

```
var value = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/
```

But I dont want the name to start or end with period(.) or underscore(_) or hyphen (-) and
this given special characters should include in middle only.

for example:

```
_name.name_@email.com Invalid
-name.name-@email.com Invalid
name.@email.com Invalid
name_@email.com Invalid
name-@email.com Invalid
.name@email.com Invalid
_name@email.com Invalid
-name@email.com Invalid
name.name@email.com Valid
name_name@email.com Valid
name-name@email.com Valid
```

I am trying to figure out the solution and learn in the process.

Comment: As usual, `var value = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/`. Note you forgot `]` before `{2,}$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
var value = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more letters/digits
- `(?:[._-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of `.`/`_`/`-` and then one or more letters/digits
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more letters/digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `[a-zA-Z]{2,}` - two or more letters
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KciNeV/1).

Answer (score -1):

Regex : `^[a-zA-Z0-9_%+-]+(\.?[a-zA-Z0-9_%+–]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$` is a working regex which satisfies following conditions

1. username : alphanumeric or `. _ % + –` these 5 special characters
2. For mail server: alphanumeric or `–` hyphen or `_` underscore in middle.
3. top level domain: contain 2-6 alphabetic characters only

In this regex the part which starts with @ `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`
is for *email server validation*

`(?:[_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of *underscore* or *hyphen* character and then one or more letters/digits

[_-] matches a single character in the list

Comment: Perhaps clearly denote how your answer differs from the currently accepted answer

Comment: This doesn’t work per OP’s requirements. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vjwLZ0/1).